# Проблема при создании сайта no such column: shop_products.date

Tags: html, python, django

Хочу создать вывод даты но выдает ошибку . Миграцию сделал. Python , django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

products.html

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for product in products_list  %}


      <div id="next-block">
        <div class="row centered">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <p><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ product.img.url }}"/></p>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <a href="/shop/{{product.id}}"> <h1> {{product.title}} </h1> </a>
                  <h3 align="right">{{products.date|date:"d-m-Y"}}</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.db import models
from django import forms

# Create your models here.

class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='')



    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from . models import Products

urlpatterns=[
    path('', ListView.as_view(queryset=Products.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:20],template_name="shop/products.html")),
    path('<int:pk>/', DetailView.as_view(model=Products, template_name="shop/product.html"))
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

vies.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.views import generic

from .models import Products


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "shop/products.html"
    context_object_name = 'products_list'


    def get_queryset(self ):
        return Products.objects.all()
```

Comment: Миграции-то применили?

Comment: Да правдо выдает ошибку при миграции